# Changing array values with text boxes

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, loops

On my form, one label should display all the names in the array and then the second array should change a name based on the location in the array.

Here is the code I have used:

```
location = int.Parse(txtLocation.Text);

        name = Convert.ToString(txtName.Text);

        string[] strOriginalNames = new string[4]; // Declares a new string variable called strOriginalNames

        strOriginalNames[0] = "John";
        strOriginalNames[1] = "Paul";
        strOriginalNames[2] = "Rodney"; // Set values to each element in the array
        strOriginalNames[3] = "David";
        strOriginalNames[4] = "Kathryn";

        foreach (string originalName in strOriginalNames)
        {
            lblOriginalNames.Text += originalName + "<br>";
        }

        strOriginalNames(location) = (name);

        foreach (string newName in strOriginalNames)
        {
            lblNewNames.Text += newName + "<br>";
        }
```

The only error is with this code snippet:

```
strOriginalNames(location) = (name);
```

Here is also a screenshot of my form:

[image]

For the code to run correctly, the second element in the array should be changed to Andrew under **New Array**

Does anyone know how to correct the error in my code?

Comment: Where is location initialized? You don´t have such a variable in your code!

Comment: You can include the error you're encountering. It will help to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
strOriginalNames[location] = name;
```

Comment: Correct, but where is location initialized, where does it´s value come from?

Comment: It think its parsed from 'txtLocation.Text'. First line. Initialisation seems to be somewhere else...

Comment: @MarcelTheis - Assume that the variable was initialized somewhere else. Anyway, I think we need to have the actual error he is referring to.

Comment: It is initialized in my code before that code snippet. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your interest sake, because Martin has answered correctly and succinctly, you can write your code like this:

```
location = int.Parse(txtLocation.Text);
name = Convert.ToString(txtName.Text);
string[] strOriginalNames = new[] { "John", "Paul", "Rodney", "David", "Kathryn" };
lblOriginalNames.Text = String.Join("<br>", strOriginalNames);
strOriginalNames[location] = name;
lblNewNames.Text = String.Join("<br>", strOriginalNames);
```

It's slightly different in that the last elements don't get a `"<br>"` after them, but I think that's probably what you'd want anyway.